# Conditional filter and groupby on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
    date    kind    sector
0   2017-02-01  P   A
1   2017-02-01  P   A
2   2017-02-01  L   A
3   2017-02-01  G   A
4   2017-02-01  P   B
5   2017-02-01  P   B
6   2017-02-01  L   B
7   2017-02-01  T   B
8   2017-02-02  P   A
9   2017-02-02  P   A
10  2017-02-02  L   A
11  2017-02-02  T   A
12  2017-02-02  A   B
13  2017-02-02  P   B
14  2017-02-02  L   B
15  2017-02-02  L   B
```

And I want to create an aggregation with the format

```
    date      sector free occupied total
   2017-02-01  A      2    2         4
   2017-02-01  B      2    2         4
   2017-02-02  A      2    2         4
   2017-02-02  A      3    1         4
```

where the rule is that if `kind == P` is occupied, else is free and the total is the sum of all entries. I tried to use `apply` on a group by but it didn´t work:

```
df.groupby(['date', 'kind']).apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'P' else 0)
```

And splitting the dataframe and combining also didn´t work:

```
df_p = df[df.kind == 'P']
df_np = df[df.kind != 'P']
df_t = df_p.groupby(['date', 'sector'], as_index=False).count()
df_nt = df_np.groupby(['date', 'sector'], as_index=False).count()
df_nt.rename(columns={'kind':'free'}, inplace=True)
df_t = pd.concat([df_t, df_nt])
```

Is there a way to do this count?

Comment: Is the last line of your desired output a mistake?

   `2017-02-01  A      3    1         4`

You seem to be repeating  `2017-02-01  A`

Comment: Fixed the typo there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two new variables for "occupied" and "free":

```
df['occupied'] = (df.kind == "P").astype(int)
df['free'] = (df.kind != "P").astype(int)
```

Then aggregate (using an `OrderedDict` here instead of a `dict` to achieve desired output column ordering):

```
df_2 = (
    df.groupby(["date","sector"])
    .agg(OrderedDict((("free" , np.sum) , ("occupied" , np.sum))))
)
```

And create your total column:

```
df_2["total"] = df_2["free"] + df_2["occupied"]
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['kind'] = df.kind.apply(lambda x: 'occupied' if x == 'P' else 'free')
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.kind).join(df).groupby(['date','sector']).sum().reset_index()
df1['total'] = df1['occupied']+df1['free']    
df1

    #          date sector  free  occupied  total
    # 0  2017-02-01      A     2         2      4
    # 1  2017-02-01      B     2         2      4
    # 2  2017-02-02      A     2         2      4
    # 3  2017-02-02      B     3         1      4
```

What you essentially do here is: you first substitute P with occupied and everything else with free in your `kind` column. Then, you categorize the values in your newly formatted `kind` with `pd.get_dummies`. That output is then joined back to your main dataframe. At this point, you can group by `date` and `sector`, and take the `sum` of each. Ultimately, you can `reset_index` and calculate the `total` column.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner to do this:

```
#group by date and sector, apply 3 functions to kind to get the sum for free, occupied and total in one go.
df.groupby(['date','sector'])['kind'].agg({'free':lambda x: sum(x!='P'),'occupied':lambda x: sum(x=='P'), 'total':len})
Out[339]: 
                   free  occupied  total
date       sector                       
2017-02-01 A          2         2      4
           B          2         2      4
2017-02-02 A          2         2      4
           B          3         1      4
```

A more verbose approach:

```
#Transform the kind column to free or occupied only
df.kind = df.kind.replace('[^P]','free',regex=True).replace('P','occupied')
#Convert kind from long to wide columns
df = pd.get_dummies(df,columns=['kind'],prefix='',prefix_sep='')
#get total
df['total']=df.free+df.occupied
#groupby and sum
df.groupby(['date','sector']).sum()
Out[322]: 
                   free  occupied  total
date       sector                       
2017-02-01 A          2         2      4
           B          2         2      4
2017-02-02 A          2         2      4
           B          3         1      4
```